# Java make better use of inheritance and abstract class

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, interface, abstract-class

I have the following structure in my project. **My question is how can I avoid adding more and more queries to abstract service?** As I keep adding modules, the lines of code in abstract service will keep increasing and I do not want that.

```
public abstract class AbstractService < T, C > implements GenericService < T, C > {

    @Autowired
    private QueryReader queryReader;

    private String readQuery(String query) {
        return queryReader.getPropertyValue(query);
    }

    public String getOrdersQuery(List < Criteria> request) {
        return addConditionsToQuery(getOrdersQuery(), request);
    }

    public String getCustomersQuery(List < Criteria> request) {
        return addConditionsToQuery(getCustomersQuery(), request);
    }

    private String addConditionsToQuery(String sql, List < Criteria> conditions) {
        return QueryHelper.addConditionsToQuery(conditions, sql);
    }


    private String getOrdersQuery() {
        return readQuery("queries.orders.retrieve");
    }

    private String getCustomersQuery() {
        return readQuery("queries.customers.retrieve");
    }

    public String updateCustomerQuery() {
        return readQuery("queries.customer.update");
    }

}
```

Generic Service goes like this -

```
public interface GenericService<T,C> {

    void update(T t);

    void create(T t);

    T search(C t);
}
```

Here is my Order service -

```
@Service
public class OrderService extends AbstractService<OrderModel, List<Criteria>> {

    @Autowired
    private OrderRepository orderRepository;

    @Override
    public OrderModel search(List<Criteria> request) {
        String query = getOrdersQuery(request);
        List<OrderEntity> orderEntities = orderRepository.findByQuery(query);
        // entity dto conversion and so on
        // ....
        return orderModel;

    }
}
```

Here is my Customer Service -

```
@Service
public class CustomerService extends AbstractService < CustomerModel, List < Criteria >> {

    @Autowired
    private CustomerRepository customerRepository;

    @Override
    public CustomerModel search(List < Criteria > request) {
        String query = getCustomersQuery(request);
        List < CustomerEntity > customerEntities = customerRepository.findByQuery(request);
        // entity dto conversion and so on
        // ....
        return customerModel;

    }

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public void update(CustomerModel request) {
        // dto to entity conversion
        // .....
        // update entity with new values 
        customerRepository.update(orderEntity, updateCustomerQuery());
    }

}
```

Comment: why would you need all those getXQuery() getYQuery()? Just put a getQuery(), and have a subclass for each X, Y, .. that implement getQuery(). Your abstract class is not supposed to know about it's child-classes.

Comment: @Stultuske I want to keep all queries at one place, rather than autowiring query reader in all places and keeping the common stuff in abstract class

Comment: Inheritance is not meant to be a place where you keep common code, but a concept that groups general-specialized elements like Person->Worker. You should not use it for things that are unrelated just because they have one thing in common - you dont want to do person extends figure just because they both happen to have a name field. Use composition it will solve your issues

Comment: @Vishal_Kotecha why would you autowire that QueryReader in the child classes? you're aware of what inheritance does, I assume?

Comment: @Stultuske Sorry I could not understand. I have autowired QueryReader in the abstract class. Please suggest me if there's any other better place.

Comment: yes, so why would you need to put it anywhere else?

Comment: @Stultuske I don't want to put it anywhere else. That's why I posted this question.

Comment: ... You have it in your parent class. If you know inheritance, you know you won't have to put it in the child classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first step, expose two protected methods:

- addConditionsToQuery
- readQuery

And get read of all the "service specific" methods. It doesn't make sense that an abstract class knows something about its children.

```
public abstract class AbstractService < T, C > implements GenericService < T, C > {

    @Autowired
    private QueryReader queryReader;

    protected String readQuery(String query) {
        return queryReader.getPropertyValue(query);
    }

    protected String addConditionsToQuery(String sql, List < Criteria> conditions) {
        return QueryHelper.addConditionsToQuery(conditions, sql);
    }
}
```

Now, the `OrdersService` for example, should know from where its query should be resolved

```
@Service
public class OrderService extends AbstractService<OrderModel, List<Criteria>> {

    @Autowired
    private OrderRepository orderRepository;

    @Override
    public OrderModel search(List<Criteria> request) {
        String sql = readQuery("queries.orders.retrieve"); 
        String query = addConditionsToQuery(sql, request);
        List<OrderEntity> orderEntities = orderRepository.findByQuery(query);
        // entity dto conversion and so on
        // ....
        return orderModel;

    }
}
```

This is alone directly answers your question.

All-in-all, since we're talking about SQLs and you have spring here, its probably not an educational project, so probably you can consider using sql management libraries like [MyBatis](https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/) that might be a good solution because it also manages SQL queries in Files (externally to the code) and provides a template engine for dynamic SQL queries Generation .

I've mentioned MyBatis only because its kind of close in design concepts to what you've presented in the question. There are also other alternatives if you don't want to deal with Hibernate/JPA/Spring Data (Jooq, jdbi to name a few).

Comment: This is exactly what I implmented after posting this question